# Selenium Webdriver does not proceed with execution after URL is loaded. The response from server is never returned and execution stays in hung state

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

IEDriverServer 3.0.0 have also used multiple versions to see if it's a config issue.
Selenium WebDriver - 3.12.0

Once the request to open the URL is sent, the control is never returned back from server. 
URL gets loaded but nothing happens after that as control is never returned and execution stays in hung state.

To be specific,

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

This is the line where it hangs. This method of passing capability to driver has been deprecated but I have tried `InternetExplorerOptions` and `InternetExplorerDriverService` but both of which doesn't work.
Below is the last line of logs after that it stays like that.

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.1.0.0
Listening on port 30830
Only local connections are allowed
2020-01-31 11:52:04 INFO   com.standardchartered.genie.downloader.Main wrapRun - DOWNLOADER START with args: "C:\Users\1596305\.genie\genie-uploader-4.jar" "https://artifactory.global.standardchartered.com/artifactory/maven-genie-release/com/standardchartered/genie/genie-uploader-4/4.1.14/genie-uploader-4-4.1.14.jar" "https://artifactory.global.standardchartered.com/artifactory/maven-genie-release/com/standardchartered/genie/genie-uploader-4/4.1.14/genie-uploader-4-4.1.14.jar.md5" "-Dbase.dir=C:\Users\1596305\.genie" "-Dinput.dir=C:\Users\1596305\.genie\input" "-Dserver.port=13579" "-Ddisplay.report=END"


2020-01-31 11:52:04 INFO   com.standardchartered.genie.downloader.Main downloadAndStartUploader - Downloading uploader from URL https://artifactory.global.standardchartered.com/artifactory/maven-genie-release/com/standardchartered/genie/genie-uploader-4/4.1.14/genie-uploader-4-4.1.14.jar to file location C:\Users\1596305\.genie\genie-uploader-4.jar.

2020-01-31 11:52:04 INFO   com.standardchartered.genie.downloader.replicator.Slf4jReplicatorListener onRejection - Will not download file. File checksum matches and file last update time is above cutoff time of 2020-01-31T05:22:04.755Z.

2020-01-31 11:52:04 INFO   com.standardchartered.genie.downloader.Main downloadAndStartUploader - Port 13579 is already used. Not starting new uploader process.

2020-01-31 11:52:04 INFO   com.standardchartered.genie.downloader.Main wrapRun - DOWNLOADER EXIT
```

and this is the exact line it fails:

```
Response response = execute(DriverCommand.NEW_SESSION, parameters);
```

It's in `RemoteWebDriver` class and response is never returned.

Comment: Which version of _Selenium_ and _IEDriverServer_ are you using?

Comment: IEDriverServer 2.5.3, 3.0.0, 3.1.0  to see if it's a config issue. Selenium WebDriver - 3.12.0

Comment: Does it work for you DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);  ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It has been deprecated in latest selenium versions.